# Rspec is returning an undefined method error when encountering capybara commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

Using rspec-rails 2.13 (I now have 2.14 specified in my gemfile, but when I installed rspec I was using 2.13) and capybara 2.0.2

I'm trying to run a test using capybara and Rspec which looks like this:

```
    require 'spec_helper'
include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

describe "add all products to regimen" do

    before(:each) do
   trainer = FactoryGirl.create(:trainer)
   client = FactoryGirl.create(:client, :trainer_id => trainer.id)
   login_as(trainer,:scope => :user)

  end

    it "changes all button to remove", :js => true do
   click 'Build Regimen'
   click_button "Click to add all products to regimen"
     page.should have_no_selector(".add-variation")
  end

    it "adds order details for each product", :js => true do
     click 'Build Regimen'
     click_button "Click to add all products to regimen"
     number_of_products = page.all('.remove-variation')
     page.should have_css("div#variation-details fieldset", :count => number_of_products.length)
    end

  end
```

Once it gets to click 'Build Regimen' it returns this error

```
←[31mundefined method `click' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0
x31991a0>←[0m
```

*Note, my test file is located in spec/features

If it helps, here's my spec_helper.rb too:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'database_cleaner'
# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include SpecTestHelper

  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

to:

```
require 'capybara'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your click inside the before block like this

```
describe "changes all button to remove", :js => true do
   before do
       click 'Build Regimen'
       click_button "Click to add all products to regimen"
   end
   it { page.should have_no_selector(".add-variation") }
end

describe "adds order details for each product", :js => true do
     before
        click 'Build Regimen'
        click_button "Click to add all products to regimen"
        @number_of_products = page.all('.remove-variation')
     end
     it { page.should have_css("div#variation-details fieldset", :count => @number_of_products.length) }
end
```